# Why does MouseEvent.toElement return Node?

Tags: dart

Why does [MouseEvent.toElement](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/MouseEvent.html#toElement) return [Node](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Node.html)?

I'd assume it should return [Element](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Element.html), or the method should be renamed toNode.

As it stands, having the dart editor warn me about accessing the style property when I write the following is less than ideal:

```
event.toElement.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's called `toElement()` to keep it aligned with what we have already in the DOM/JavaScript land. It was named by Microsoft long ago and has been adopted in several browsers today. So, I think in Dart we wanted to keep the same name.

However, whether we should annotate it to return `Node` or `Element`, that's a good question. I believe in almost every (if not all) cases the returned object is indeed an `Element` and it would be nicer if it was typed to return an `Element`. However, there may be corner cases where it actually returns a `Node` (remember, elements extend nodes). With quick testing, I couldn't find any such case. Maybe with manual event firing.

Maybe the Dart engineer behind this choice can shed us some light.